# SQL Server query questions

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, `tblRooms` and `tblReservations`. Each table has a `UnitId`.

When a room in `tblRooms` is reserved for a specific date, a record in is created in `tblReservations` with the `UnitId` and the reservation date.

How would I write a SQL query to list all the rooms in `tblRooms` that do not have a reservation on a specific date in `tblReservations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tblRooms t1
LEFT JOIN tblReservations t2
    ON t1.UnitId = t2.UnitId AND
       t2.reservation_date = '2017-01-30'
WHERE t2.UnitId IS NULL
```

Comment: I even know who will do this :D but just can't prove it. I did upvote to nullify your downvote

Comment: Yes, @strawberry will do this, we all know it.

Comment: I didn't mean strawberry.. I haven't seen him regular here

Comment: He mainly does MySQL, but he is known for harsh downvotes.  Not sure about SQL Server I guess.

Comment: This answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblRooms t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   tblReservations tr
                   WHERE  t.UnitId = tr.UnitId
                          AND reservation_date = '2017-01-30') -- pass specific date here
```

Where there is a match for a `UnitId` inside the sub-query, then the particular `UnitId` will not returned

Comment: Being new to this community, Can anyone tell me why my question was not well received by this community?